# Stream audio with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioengine

I'm developing an application that should record a user's voice and stream it to a custom device via the MQTT protocol.
The audio specification for the custom device: little-endian, unsigned, 16-bit LPCM at 8khz sample rate. Packets should be 1000 bytes each.

I'm not familiar with AudioEngine and I found this sample of code which I believe fits my case:

```
func startRecord() {
    audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    let bus = 0
    let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
    let inputFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: bus)
    
    var streamDescription = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
    streamDescription.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM.littleEndian
    streamDescription.mSampleRate = 8000.0
    streamDescription.mChannelsPerFrame = 1
    streamDescription.mBitsPerChannel = 16
    streamDescription.mBytesPerPacket = 1000
    
    
    let outputFormat = AVAudioFormat(streamDescription: &streamDescription)!
    
    guard let converter: AVAudioConverter = AVAudioConverter(from: inputFormat, to: outputFormat) else {
        print("Can't convert in to this format")
        return
    }
    
    inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: inputFormat) { (buffer, time) in
        print("Buffer format: \(buffer.format)")
        
        var newBufferAvailable = true
        
        let inputCallback: AVAudioConverterInputBlock = { inNumPackets, outStatus in
            if newBufferAvailable {
                outStatus.pointee = .haveData
                newBufferAvailable = false
                return buffer
            } else {
                outStatus.pointee = .noDataNow
                return nil
            }
        }
        
        let convertedBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: outputFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(outputFormat.sampleRate) * buffer.frameLength / AVAudioFrameCount(buffer.format.sampleRate))!
        
        var error: NSError?
        let status = converter.convert(to: convertedBuffer, error: &error, withInputFrom: inputCallback)
        assert(status != .error)
        
        print("Converted buffer format:", convertedBuffer.format)
    }
    
    audioEngine.prepare()
    
    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {
        print("Can't start the engine: \(error)")
    }
    
}
```

But currently, the converter can't convert the input format to my output format and I don't understand why.
If I change my output format to something like that:

```
let outputFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: 8000.0, channels: 1, interleaved: false)!
```

Then it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `streamDescription` is wrong, you hadn't filled in all the fields, and `mBytesPerPacket` was wrong - this is not the same kind of packet your protocol calls for. For uncompressed audio (like LPCM) `AudioStreamBasicDescription` requires this field to be 1. If your protocol requires samples to be in groups of 1000, then you will have to do that.

Try this

```
var streamDescription = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
streamDescription.mSampleRate = 8000.0
streamDescription.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM
streamDescription.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger // no endian flag means little endian
streamDescription.mBytesPerPacket = 2
streamDescription.mFramesPerPacket = 1
streamDescription.mBytesPerFrame = 2
streamDescription.mChannelsPerFrame = 1
streamDescription.mBitsPerChannel = 16
streamDescription.mReserved = 0
```